# Stop program flow in the middle without using an exception

Tags: c++

I need to stop the program flow in the middle, and I am currently using an exception for this. This flow is the legal flow and I want to know if I can do it without using an exception.

This is an example of my code, and I cannot change `func_2` and `func_1`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void func_3()
{
    printf("i am func_3\n");
    throw 20;
    printf("i am not supposed to be here\n");
}
void func_2()
{
    printf("i am func_2\n");
    func_3();
    printf("i am not supposed to be here\n");
}
void func_1()
{
    printf("i am func_1\n");
    func_2();
    printf("i am not supposed to be here\n");
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        func_1();
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        printf("i am supposed to be here\n");
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        printf("i am not supposed to be here\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `return;`?

Comment: Try this:  int *i = 0;  *i=20;

Comment: @JBentley When you return in `func_3`, how do you make `func_2` and `func_1` **not** execute their second `printf`? I guess that's what OP wants, without exceptions, without modifying `func_1/2`.

Comment: You could try setjmp and longjmp

Comment: This is too out of context to give a useful, general answer.

Comment: `setjmp/longjmp` but that's just an uglier version of exceptions. What's wrong with using an exception here, this kind of flow is exactly what they are designed for... Unless you actually mean to `exit`, of course.

Comment: @leemes Good point, I didn't catch on to that part of the requirements.

Comment: I strongly discourage to misuse exceptions to control program flow logic. Use them to handle exceptional situations (like errors unrecoverable at your actual point).

Comment: I don't mean to exit the flow, and I am trying to find other solutions beside exceptions - but based on the answers I understand that exceptions are the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to handle an exceptional case and are looking for an alternative to exceptions. I.e. I hope you don't want to continue with the program "normally" after handling your exceptional case, which is possible but not recommended to implement with exceptions.

Possible but not recommended alternatives to exceptions are:

- When you want to stop your whole application, then you can use [`std::exit(0);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit). You can implement your "catch"-code in a function which you call instead of your "throw"-statement, and call `std::exit(0);` at the end of that function (or use another exit code to indicate an "unsuccessful" exit). Or you implement an exit handler and register it using [`std::atexit(&handle_exit);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit).

  Alternative to `std::exit(<something>);` is [`abort();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) which throws the POSIX signal "SIGABRT" to indicate abnormal termination (which is the default behavior if your program throws and doesn't catch an exception). Your "catch"-code would then go in a signal handler which you register using the POSIX functions. Note that this requires a POSIX system and is thus not as portable as other solutions.
- Another (similar) option is to use the "terminate" mechanism: Call [`std::terminate();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) when you would normally throw your exception. Put your "catch"-code in a "terminate handler" function with signature `void(*)()`, i.e. no parameters and no return value, let's call the function `void handle_terminate()`. Install a terminate handler using [`std::set_terminate(&handle_terminate);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate). I didn't try that one, however, and it sounds damn ugly.
- You *could* implement an exception-like behavior using assembly instructions, but please **do not try this at home**, as the behavior of such code is highly implementation defined (if not undefined), and way too ugly to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`Return` can be used to return to the caller and stop the function being executed

```
 int GLOBAL_FLAG = 1;

function called_function(){
    printf("Inside Function")
    if(/*some condition*/)
         {
           GLOBAL_FLAG = 0;
           return;
         }
    /*Normal function code*/
}



  int main(){
    {
    called_function();
    if(GLOBAL_FLAG == 1)/*continue program execution*/
    printf("Function had been executed.Back to normal flow")
    }
```

So once the return statement is encountered it goes back to the `caller` that is `main` here and continues executing rest of the statements in `main` function.

Comment: Note: OP says can't modify `func_1` and `func_2`, which makes a `return` not work, since remaining code in `func_1` and `func_2` would still be called after `func_3` returns.

Comment: Nope, because `func_1` gets called, and it calls `func_2` (both of those *not* modifyable), which then calls `func_3` (apparently the only modifiable function). It is `func_3` that need to be able to skip back out to `main` without any code executed until it gets to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

In short, *you can't* (well ... you could, by using jumps instead, but then you would have *two* problems to solve).

The exception solution is the one to use, but do not throw a number (a number - especially a magical number in this case doesn't tell you anything).

Instead, define a `struct func_3_interrupted {};` minimalistic structure, whose type name tells you it is an "interruption" of func_3, and catch that instead; The structure should be empty (or close to empty) and it should probably *not* inherit from the `std::exception` hierarchy.